# Allow Both VPN access and Internet access to Azure Web App

Tags: azure

I have a Web App behind Azure Front and a Waf Policy fronting a browser based application. Users are connecting via internet in a browser.
I need to interface with some external servers trough Foritgate VPN as IPSEC is required.
I created a VPN set up in Azure and have a connection with VPN up and working and added a Private endpoint to the web app.
Testing this I realized I am locked out from the normal internet access when the VPN is active.
Is there a way to allow both Traffic over VPN and Internet.
I am not very familiar with Azure so any advice would be useful

Answer (score 0):

I read up some on the Hybrid Connections and it seem as it is only supporting outbound traffic from the Web App. To get it to work i set up a new azure Front and added a private endpoint Connecting with the Fortigate VPN. The main thing is the SKU of the Front door need to be Premium to support this solution. The one in use was standard and not supporting Private Endpoints